# Adding all wrong answers into an array with Java - how?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I want to take all the questions that were answered incorrectly (it's a simple program asking math questions) and if they got the question wrong, add the question number to the array for further use.

But, I don't know how long this array will be, it could theoretically be of a different length each time the program is ran. So how would I set up the array?

Comment: Lots of people have already answered with ArrayList. My only addition is that you should remember that in Java the reference of the array has no restriction in the size, you can do `int[] myArray = new int[2];myArray = new int[4];int k=21;myArray = new int[21]`. But this is not related to resizing, all those arrays are independent between them.

Comment: You should also post what you have done so far along with your question. At least what you have tried to do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.

You could do something like:

```
ArrayList<String> wrongAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();

// Call this function with the user's answer as a parameter, when the answer
// has been determined to be incorrect.
public void wrongAnswer(String answer) {
    wrongAnswers.add(answer);
}

public void printWrongAnswers() {
    System.out.println("Wrong answers:");
    for (String answer : wrongAnswers) {
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into using an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). This is an implementation of the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface that is backed by an array.

Using the default constructor, it will start with a backing array of size 10 (but don't worry too much about this detail):

```
List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

You can then add elements:

```
questionList.add(question);
```

It will then resize this array as needed as you continue to add elements.

Answer (score 1):

Start with an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and then you can call [toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29) to get an actual array.

You can also initialize an array whose size is the number of questions you have. Then keep a running count of missed questions, and simply trim the array at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Since you probably know how many questions you are going to ask, you can stick to the array if you like and make it exactly as long as the number of questions you have. I would like to see the first person who succeeds in answering more questions incorrect then the number of questions available on the test

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection, like a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementation (like [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)), instead of an array. Then you can add by calling `list.add(miss)` and never worry about the size.

Do you specifically need an array? You can get the array, but in general, it's rare to specifically need one for requirements like these.

Comment: Yeah, it's a CS assignment where we're specifically told to use arrays at one point.

Comment: @DougSmith Then size it to the number of questions; that's the most a user could get wrong.